# How pre-load drivers for a WiFi USB device that can't use "update driver" from Device Manager. Where do I put them?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

In XP, I used to dump USB driver files into system32, but that's not working as smoothly with Win7.

I just want to know where to put the files (3 of them, `.cat`, `.sys`, `.inf`) so that Windows knows where to look to find them.

Answer (score -1):

Got it using the above command:

```
PnPUtil -i -a <InfName>.inf
```